# Using javascript to load an image from another site

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
    function displayimage(x,target){
    x.success(function(realData){

  var content = $(realData);
  var imageurl = content.find('img').eq(1)[0].outerHTML;
  var urlTrimmed= String(imageurl).substr(37);
  var result = $urlTrimmed.substr(0,$urlTrimmed.length-34);
  console.log(result);
  document.getElementById("item1").style.backgroundImage = "url('result')";
```

Result gives me a working image url taken from another site.

However it doesn't load... when I replace "result" with the link, it works.. however, it needs to be dynamicly... Any ideas?

Comment: you have jQuery , yet u still mix in vanilla..

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the strings.

```
document.getElementById("item1").style.backgroundImage = "url('"+ result + "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You're actually setting the image to the `url('result');`. Literally the word "result". Probably not what you mean. Try:

```
document.getElementById("item1").style.backgroundImage = 
  "url('" + result + "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotes inside url() as:

```
document.getElementById("item1").style.backgroundImage = "url('"+result+"')";
```